# Moving button element to different div(parent) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, html, dom

I have a button  on a aspx page  should be positioned  on table for one criteria  and for other  it should be positioned on different div (I dont have the access to code behind for programmatic adding )  all i have to do is though javascript   what would be the best way to  move the button position?

```
<div id= "main">
    <table>
        <tr><td id="loginsbtbtn"></td><tr>
    <table>
    <div id="cbtn">
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit"  BackColor="#b5c7de" runat="server" Text='continue' /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you give us a code snipplet

Comment: <div id= "main"> <table> <tr> <td id="loginsbtbtn"> </td> <tr> <table> <div id="cbtn"> <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" BackColor="#b5c7de" runat="server" Text='continue' /> </div> </div>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using jQuery, do this:

```
$('#myButton').appendTo('#someDiv');
```

Without jQuery, do this:

```
document.getElementById('someDiv').appendChild(document.getElementById('myButton'));
```

This assumes the targeted elements have ID attributes. Impossible to give an exact solution without any HTML in the question.

Comment: <div id= "main">
<table>
<tr>
<td id="loginsbtbtn">
</td>

<tr>
<table>

<div id="cbtn">


<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit"  BackColor="#b5c7de" runat="server" Text='continue' /> 

</div>


</div>